# Summary Formula Where Field Equals

Tags: reporting, report-formula

I have a report where there is a status of the lead. I want to see how many leads have the status of scheduled as a percentage of all leads in a report.

I've never done this before and can't figure out how to even start.

```
RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, STATUS == "Scheduled")
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following if you're able to group your rows (maybe by owner, for reporting on sales moving leads to a certain status).

1. Create a number [row-level formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm&type=0) that denotes whether your criteria (where) is met. If it is met, give it a 1 (for counting).

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(STATUS,"Scheduled"),
    1,
    0
)
```

2. Create a [Summary Formula column](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=building_custom_summary_formulas.htm&type=0) as a percentage. Use the left sidebar to insert your field you created above (ex. `CDF1:SUM`)

```
{insert row-level formula created above} / RowCount
```

This should give you a percentage of how many records meet your criteria in a given report by Lead owner (or other grouped field)

[image]

If you're not able to group it by some sort of field, you'd be left with just step 1 (and a sum of all leads that meet your criteria). You can easily take the sum of the row-level formula and compare with the amount of total records in the report as highlighted below:

[image]

Comment: explained amazingly, thank you.